# In .NET, when do I have to reference a DLL that an external library also references?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'm trying to understand when it's necessary for my .NET project to reference a DLL that an external library references.

A practical example: Microsoft.Bot.Builder depends on Chronic.Signed.dll

If I reference Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll, do I always have to also add a reference to Chronic.Signed.dll in my own project, even if I'm not using it directly? Or do I only have to only under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I reference Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll, do I always have to also add
>   a reference to Chronic.Signed.dll in my own project, even if I'm not
>   using it directly? Or do I only have to only under certain
>   circumstances?

When you add packages using NuGet, dependent packages are also installed with them. So when you will add Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll it will automatically install the Chronic.Signed.dll as well.

Now comes the part, Why? Some lib packages are dependent on other packages. Like a function in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll might be using some helper or main function from Chronic.Signed.dll. So if you will remove the reference of Chronic.Signed.dll you will will get error of missing dependency or reference.

> do I always have to also add
>        a reference to Chronic.Signed.dll in my own project, even if I'm not
>        using it directly?

Yes, Because Microsoft.bot is using it internally.

Not all packages depends on others. Some are independent and never install any other dlls but some do.

Comment: Well, you don't need to reference other assemblies if you don't reference anything in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll that uses them...

Comment: @RufusL Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this when you make use of something in `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` that exposes something from `Chronic.Signed` in its public API.  For example (and without going through the libraries myself), let's say `Chronic.Signed.IFoo` is an interface that `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FooImpl` implements.  If you reference `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FooImpl` in your code then you also need to reference `Chronic.Signed` so that your code has access to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're referencing specific things from those packages, you shouldn't need to. If you're missing a dependency which would cause your code to be unable to compile or run, the compiler will most likely complain about it.

Just as a simple example of when multiple DLLs need to be installed, when you're installing packages through NuGet, sometimes packages will have dependencies that will install in order to be able to run the code in the package. However, most of them will install independently of any other packages. You can test the how this works across projects by putting some references in a library project that don't exist in another project, and then trying to run the code from the main project. You shouldn't need to reference the same DLLs as the library project.